# Assembly - Simple lock/unlock program bug

Tags: assembly, mips

The program I wrote has a bug and I can't understand why. It's supposed to set status to lock/unlock after user presses any key, with some feedback. But after two cycles the output goes wrong. Example:

`The door is locked
Press any key to unlock
The door is unlocked
Press any key to lock
The door is locked
q
The door is unlocked
q
The door is locked
q
The door is unlocked
q`

q is the button I pressed.

Here is the code. I would appreciate any help.

```
## program for a simple door locking device
## register use:    $v0: stores syscall code
##                  $a0: stores entered number
##                  $s0: stores status number

.data
    locked:     .asciiz "The door is locked\n"
    unlocked:   .asciiz "The door is unlocked\n"
    unlock:     .asciiz "Press any key to unlock\n"
    lock:       .asciiz "Press any key to lock\n"

.text
.globl main

main:

# store default status value
ori $s0, $0, 1      # store the default 1

# output the status
li $v0, 4           # system call code for print_str
la $a0, locked      # print "The door is locked"
syscall

loop: 

bgtz $s0, unlocking     # if $s0 > 0, start unlocking
beq $s0, $0, locking    # if $s0 = 0, start locking

unlocking:  

# output the user instruction
li $v0, 4               # system call code for print_str
la $a0, unlock          # print "Press any key to unlock"
syscall

# ask for input
li $v0, 8               # system call code for read_str
syscall

# set status to unlocked (0)
ori $s0, $0, 0      

# output new status
li $v0, 4               # system call code for print_str
la $a0, unlocked        # print "The door is unlocked"
syscall

j loop  

locking:

# output the user instruction
li $v0, 4               # system call code for print_str
la $a0, lock            # print "Press any key to lock"
syscall

# ask for input
li $v0, 8 # system call code for read_str
syscall

# set status to locked (1)
ori $s0, $0, 1  

# output new status
li $v0, 4           # system call code for print_str
la $a0, locked      # print "The door is locked"
syscall     

j loop
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `read_str` you need to set a0 to point at a dummy input buffer, otherwise you overwrite whatever a0 happens to be pointing at. You also need to set a1 to the number of characters to read.

Note that syscall 12, which just reads a single character, would probably be a better choice.

See [list of syscalls](http://students.cs.tamu.edu/tanzir/csce350/reference/syscalls.html).